# Spring IDE / STS : Can I get autocompletions of beans from other files?

Tags: eclipse, spring

When writing XML beans and using "**ref**=" everything works well as long as beans are declared in one file. But when bean is in other file, I can't get any autocompletion.

Doesn't work in Spring Tools Suite 2.8.1 or Eclipse 3.7.1 with Spring IDE plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either import the other file or create a config set that groups all the files.

[Spring/Eclipse 'referenced bean not found' warning when using <import>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868412/spring-eclipse-referenced-bean-not-found-warning-when-using-import)