# spring-beans.xsd does not define "local". Why?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

Almost every spring project uses spring-beans.xsd (refers to it to be more precise). However, if you look at the file, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd, you'll see that it is version 3.2 and doesn't have a definition for the attribute "local".

What's even more interesting, is that http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd does actually define "local".

Also since the file is pulled out of the jar (org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd) due to spring.schema, I don't think any project will have compile or runtime issues.

Eclipse's xml validator on the other hand, I think, uses only the internet link and shows an xml error, more specifically :

*"cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in element 'ref'"*

Is this is a bug?

Edit:
As per request, this is my spring header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">
```

Edit 2: here is where I'm using local

```
    <bean id="bar" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref local="foo" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="foo" class="java.lang.String" />
```

Comment: Please show us the XML you are trying to validate with Eclipse. Edit your question.

Comment: if you go to http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/ .. you will see the version doesnt even matter.

Comment: @Ashish What do you mean version doesn't matter? That's not even my question. I'm saying two files, in this case, spring-beans.xsd and spring-beans-3.2.xsd say they are the same version but one defines the "local" attribute and the other doesn't.

Comment: if it was an answer I'd have put that in answer section. That was a comment and what I meant was if go to that link and look for the version in last three files , you 'd find the same version. So it looks like the attribute "local" no longer exists in current versions.

Comment: Please post where you are trying to use `local`.

Answer (score 37):

You should try to use `<ref bean="someBean"/>` instead.

Answer (score 16):

As stated here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

> The ***local*** attribute on the ***ref*** element is no longer supported in the 4.0 beans xsd since it does not provide value over a regular bean reference anymore. Simply change your existing ***ref local*** references to ***ref bean*** when upgrading to the 4.0 schema.

As you might know Spring 3.x is not fully compatible with java 8, so you either use unsupported and outdated Java 7 with Spring 3.x, or upgrade both Spring and JDK. I would strongly recommend the latest

Answer (score 3):

The http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd actually points to the 4.0 XSD, which does NOT have *local*. Additionally, There are bugs in eclipse with spring integration that could be the issue. [INT-1353](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-1353?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

Additionally, there /was/ a configuration option for eclipse to specify loading XSDs from Classpath, but I'm not 100% sure this works or even exists anymore. There is a screenshot of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896051/1958771

```
~ sheenobu -> curl -s http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd | md5
0483a5565138fe9f79c5fbe38c7c5969
~ sheenobu -> curl -s http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd | md5
1562baeab9550e2149e9608dbb3bbadd
~ sheenobu -> curl -s http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd | md5
0483a5565138fe9f79c5fbe38c7c5969
```

Comment: Look at the version of  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
It clearly says version 3.2.



"![CDATA[
Spring XML Beans Schema, version 3.2 Authors: Juergen Hoeller, Rob Harrop, Mark Fisher, Chris Beams This defines a simple and consistent way of creating a namespace of JavaBeans objects, managed by a Spring BeanFactory, read by XmlBeanDefinitionReader ...
]]"

Comment: It is a typo or mis-labeled, it's not 3.2 . Updated my answer to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring (and Eclipse) will use whichever `xsd` you declared in the `schemaLocation` regardless of the one in the `jar` file. This is actually validation done by the XML parser that Spring uses underneath it all.

If you want to use the `local` attribute of `ref`, you will need to declare a `schemaLocation` that points to a schema that has the `local` attribute. Note that if you do do this, the generated context will need to be parseable by the `BeanDefinitionParser` that exists in your Spring `jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with using older  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd in xsi:schemaLocation. (As my project is "older" as well)